# Move 100 bytes from end of file to beginning of file with Java (RandomAccessFile is too slow)

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, randomaccessfile, bufferedinputstream

I have a need to move the last 100 bytes of a file to the beginning of the file with Java (on android).  After doing some research, I have a working solution, but it is way too slow for some of the larger files I'm working with (up to 2GB).  I tried using the read() method on the RandomAccessFile object originally and it was far too slow, so after some more digging, I found an alternative method to use a BufferedInputStream but it doesn't appear to increase the performance at all.

I'm thinking there's got to be a simpler, easier, faster way to do this.

Here is the working code I have that is just too slow:

```
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sam.dll");
    RandomAccessFile f;
    OutputStream f1;
    try {
        f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        long size = file.length();
        f.seek(size - 100);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getFD());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        try {

            f1 = new FileOutputStream(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sam.dl4")));
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                f1.write(bis.read());
            }
            f.seek(0);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            for(int j =0; j < size - 100;j++) {
                f1.write(f.read());
            }
            f.close();
            f1.close();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("blah",e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any suggestions for ways I can speed this up?  Am I going about this entirely the wrong way?  I set it up with C# with a FileStream object and it shifts the bytes in seconds (even for 2GB files) but with the method above, it's literally taking hours.

TIA

Comment: This doesn't even make any sense. 100 bits isn't an integral number of bytes.

Comment: When comparing to C# where are you running your comparison - on a Windows machine with different CPU/IO characteristics or on Android via Xamarian/mono?

Comment: Don't read and write bytewise. Allocate some buffers and read and write in chunks of some KB.

Comment: @blafasel I think that's where my disconnect is.  In c# I'm dong it in chunks of 4096 (other than the swap bytes which is a byte array of 100).  Unfortunately I'm not a Java guru so I'm not sure how syntactically to write that to my outputstream.  If you could show me a sample of some code for Java, that'd help heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated bytewise I/O operations drain performance.

The approriate way would be:

- allocate a buffer of appropriate size
- have your `InputStream` fill the buffer in one or very few I/O operations
- manipulate the buffer
- have your `OutputStream` flush the buffer to disk in one or very few I/O operations

In Java (only using classes you already used):

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
// lengthRead is the count of bytes read
int lengthRead = inputStream.read(buf);
doBufferMagic(buf, lengthRead);
outputStream.write(buf, 0, lengthRead);
```